# Shade Smooth with Geometry Nodes not working on Rendering (Cycles)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, geometry-nodes

I'm new to Blender and I'm trying to learn Geometry Nodes but I'm facing an issue:
When I try to Shade Smooth with Geometry Nodes seems to **only work on Viewport.**

I've generated Cylinders and Spheres meshes via Geometry Nodes using the **"Set Shade Smooth"** node.

It seems to work in the viewport, but when I'll try to render it, it's **rendered as "Shade Flat".**

Following there's the **Viewport** example with the Nodes:
[image]

Here instead the **Rendering** results:
[image]

**Could you please help me identify the issue?
Is It a known bug?**

Thank You in advance.

Comment: This *Mesh Transformation* node group seems to have also a *Shade Smooth* option. Have you checked if this input is properly connected and works?

Comment: can u provide blend file?

Comment: The "Mesh Transformation" node has the "Shade Smooth" trigger because the "Set Shade Smooth" was here before.
I moved it out to "debug".
I've also uploaded the Blend file, it's a bit messy due to debugging and testing, but I hope that's clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that just for the **Spheres**, I've solved the issue by setting the Rotation of the mesh **X axis to 0°.**
It's a Sphere, the rotation shouldn't affect the way it's visualized.

Following the Blend file and the **Mesh Transformation** Node:
[image]
The **"Shade Smooth" input** is present but not linked because previously the "Set Shade Smooth" node was here.

**Blend File:** [image]